# Capistrano 3.7.2: LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/scm/git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano3

Doing a fresh bundle on an app that has worked with Capistrano 3.5.x and it throws this error on a `cap production deploy:*` task (any deploy subtask)

`LoadError: cannot load such file -- capistrano/scm/git`

Here's Capfile:

```
# Load DSL and Setup Up Stages
require 'capistrano/setup'

# Includes default deployment tasks
require 'capistrano/deploy'

require "capistrano/scm/git"
install_plugin Capistrano::SCM::Git

require 'capistrano/rvm'
# require 'capistrano/rbenv'
# require 'capistrano/chruby'
require 'capistrano/bundler'
require 'capistrano/rails/assets'
require 'capistrano/rails/migrations'
require 'capistrano/passenger'
require 'sshkit/sudo'
require 'capistrano/sitemap_generator'

# Loads custom tasks from `lib/capistrano/tasks' if you have any defined.
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.cap').each { |r| import r }
Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/**/*.rb').each { |r| import r }
require 'appsignal/capistrano'
```

Comment: Check `Gemfile.lock` - are you sure you use Capistrano version 3.7.2? That `scm` folder is present in versions 3.7.0 and above

Comment: What does `cap -v` command say?

Comment: Ahhhh 3.5.0 still. That might be the issue.

Comment: Yup. That was it. Thanks @IlyaKonyukhov

Comment: You're welcome :)